# Can I use Gmail on Google Apps as OpenID provider?

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email, openid

We use Gmail on Google Apps for email for our small company using our on domain-name. Now I would like to use the email-addresses with OpenID.

Is there any way I can use Gmail on Google Apps as OpenID provider?

I can not login on gmail.com with these email-addresses, and the URL to the Google Apps Gmail wasn't valid as a OpenID provider here on StackExchange.

I would like to use the Google Apps as a provider, so the users just have to manage one password for email, and login to other sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like this was enabled last year. Here is the blog-post:

http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/07/google-apps-openid-identity-hub-for.html

> Note: The Federated Login Service is
>   disabled by default for Google Apps
>   Premier and Education Editions. The
>   domain admin can enable it from the
>   Control Panel at
>   `http://www.google.com/a/cpanel/<your-domain>/SetupIdp.`

The OpenID URL for Google Apps is something like:

```
https://www.google.com/a/<your-domain>/o8/ud?be=o8
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks interesting, but it doesn't seem to work here: `No OpenID endpoint found.` and I don't know any other place I could test on.

Comment: If you are the admin for the domain, you could use this article:
http://jeremiahlee.com/blog/2009/09/28/how-to-setup-openid-with-google-apps/

Comment: Yes, I'm the admin, and we use the Standard edition, so i should be activated by default, but it doesn't seem to work. I will try the steps in the article, thanks.